# Is there a way to run only specific test from a class with Ant and JUnit?

Tags: junit, ant

MOTIVATION: at the moment I have multiple test suites written in Java which I can build and run by Ant. I develop and polish tests on my laptop and they run every night on a remote machine in the cloud. Sometimes it may happen for various reasons that locally some specific test passes but it permanently fails in the cloud. Then I need to debug. How I do it now: I add @Ignore annotation to all tests except the one I need to debug, commit my code, then connect remotely to the machine in the cloud to see what is going on on my laptop and then run the suite in the cloud. This way only one test from the suite executes and via RDP I can see what is failing. This is something I can live with but it bothers me to add these @Ignore annotations and then remove them from all tests except for one when debugging. Would be great if there is a way in Ant to tell the target not to run a specific class which executes all tests but only one particular test instead.

Example of my Ant target for one particular suite:

```
<target name="ADMPSmokeTest">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr" showoutput="true">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <test name="me.enreach.automation.sanoma.SmokeTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="QARegression.classpath"/>
        </junit>
</target>
```

As you can see the `<test name="me.enreach.automation.sanoma.SmokeTest" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>` says it needs to run all tests in the `SmokeTest` class.
Can I somehow tell it to run only let's say `SmokeTest.createCampaign` ?
Please advise only solutions which really can save time, do not say things like "create separate test suite when you need to debug", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can add a `methods` attribute to the `test` element. This is supposed to allow you to provide a comma separated list of method names from the class specified in the `name` attribute, though I have not been able to get it to work with more than one method.

Example:

```
<test name="me.enreach.automation.sanoma.SmokeTest" methods="createCampaign"/>
```

Support for `methods` was added in Ant 1.8.2.